# Search SQL Server database and get part of sentence, matching with the keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using simple search SQL to search the table for matching search keyword or string.

I want something like BBC search http://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=florida

It get text around the matching keywords.

For example I have a `News` table and I need to get 10 words around the matched keyword.

```
NewsID Title      Detail
1      xxxx       <p> Hello How are you! is this the word you are looking for.</p>
2      yyyy       <p> this is the detail of second news of today. </p>
```

Right now I use simple select statement to search

```
SELECT * 
FROM News 
WHERE Detail LIKE '%word%'
```

This matched with first row.

Now I need to get the two or three words before & after the matching keyword like

```
Is this the word you are
```

Not sure how this can be don't using SQL Server function or CTE query.

We can do this using C# & Regex but this will be too heavy as search has to go through thousands of records and `Details` column of news table can have up to 1000 words or more for each news item.

Just want to mention I don't have `FreeText` search option on the server

Appreciate pointer to resolve this in best & optimized way

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this:
Now i need to get the two or three words before & after the matching keyword like

Comment: I mean if i search for `word` in then it should get me the record with whcih it matches & result should show me `this the word you are` i.e two words before & after the match which in this case is `word`

Comment: You get the whole line, work out the positions of delimiters (space) using `CHARINDEX` then use `SUBSTRING` to pull it all out

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I will try your approach

Comment: Here's an example of a big ugly inline way to find the word and the following two words. It hideous but it works. `SELECT 
SearchME,
CHARINDEX('word',SearchME) Found,
CHARINDEX(' ',SearchME,CHARINDEX(' ',SearchME,CHARINDEX(' ',SearchME,CHARINDEX('word',SearchME))+1)+1) SecondSpacePos ,
SUBSTRING(
SearchME,
CHARINDEX('word',SearchME),
CHARINDEX(' ',SearchME,CHARINDEX(' ',SearchME,CHARINDEX(' ',SearchME,CHARINDEX('word',SearchME))+1)+1)-CHARINDEX('word',SearchME)
)
FROM 
(
SELECT 'Hello How are you! is this the word you are looking for' AS SearchMe
) F`

Comment: Instead of "two or three words" could you find a set number of characters before and after the search word?  Is it possible for the word to appear more than once and if so do you care?

Comment: @Jericho, I can do either. But word is more appropriate thing to do

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, This working but fails if keyword match the last work.

Comment: Yes it will fail in many circumstances. You can make it work by wrapping it in case statements etc. and you can see how big and hideous it's going to get.